# emacs: how add a ") to a block of text

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have a block of code like this:

```
ec2_shell_exec(tag: "ls /
ec2_shell_exec(tag: "sudo yum install git-core
ec2_shell_exec(tag: "pwd
```

Whats the easiest way to add a `")` to this block of code?

Please note, emacs runs in terminal mode aka -nw mode.

Comment: Personlly, I use [multiple-cursor](https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el) to do this. Or you can use keyboard macro. Writing a function for this single operation seems a bit overhead.

Comment: can i place the multiple cursors at the end of lines, when the lines are of different length?

Comment: Multiple-cursor is a rich package. One of its functions is to help changing things which have similar pattern. I will first highlight `ec2_shell_exec(tag`. And call `mc/mark-all-like-this` which is from multiple-cursor. You will see all `ec2_shell_exec(tag` being hightlighted. Now call `end-of-line` to move every cursor to the end. Finally, you can insert anything you want. Press `C-g` to end operation.

Comment: Here is a youtube video showing a demonstration [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNa3axo40qM).

Answer (score 3):

## Interactively

<kbd>C-M-% $ RET ") RET</kbd>

- don't forget to press **4** keys at the same time: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> for `C`, <kbd>Alt</kbd> for `M`, and <kbd>Shift-5</kbd> for `%`
- if the above still does not work (e.g., you are in a terminal with `emacs -nw`), you can do <kbd>M-x query-replace-regexp RET $ RET ") RET</kbd>

## Programmatically

```
(while (not (eobp)) ; you have to edit the condition!
  (goto-char (line-end-position))
  (insert "\")")
  (forward-line))
```

Comment: when I press C-M-% $ emacs adds five dollar signs and gives message "C-u 5 $"

Comment: You need to also press `Shift` to effect `%` instead of `5`.

Comment: Note that this key combination might not be available in all terminals when you're running `emacs -nw`.

Comment: i was looking for a interactive solution, and the one provided by sds didnt work for me (perhaps because i was in a osx terminal)

Comment: @joshsverns: try `M-x query-replace-regexp RET $ RET ") RET`.

Answer (score 1):

A [keyboard macro](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyboardMacros) should be  easy to type on most terminals:

- Move to your first line
- Start recording a keyboard macro with <kbd>C-x (</kbd>
- Go to end of line with <kbd>C-e</kbd>
- Type <kbd>")</kbd>
- Move down with <kbd>C-n</kbd>
- Stop recording macro with <kbd>C-x )</kbd>
- Type <kbd>C-x e</kbd> to replay once
- Type <kbd>e</kbd> for each successive time you need to repeat it

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing the two solutions here (for folks running emacs in terminal):

```
M-x query-replace-regexp RET $ RET ") RET
```

And

```
first highlight ec2_shell_exec(tag. And call mc/mark-all-like-this which is from multiple-cursor. You will see all ec2_shell_exec(tag being hightlighted. Now call end-of-line to move every cursor to the end. Finally, you can insert anything you want. Press C-g to end operation
```

video demo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNa3axo40qM

Thanks adobe and tom!